# iphone/android - How to quickly crypt/decrypt a huge number of critical data on mobile devices? Which strategy would you use?

Tags: android, iphone, encryption

I will develop a mobile application on Android and iPhone/iPad that will contain a huge number of data (several MB, let's say 50 MB). Thus, these data will be stored on an external storage like a SD card.

Besides, they are critical and user **must not** be able to read them!!!

I guess **how could I crypt/decrypt these data?**

Here the main points to keep in mind:

1. Application is running on mobile device:

   - **limited ressources** (CPU, memory...)
2. These data will be read-only :

   - need only to develop the **decrypt feature** on the device
3. Application must quickly react:

   - **response time to decrypt** must be shortest as possible

Note: just a few amount of these data have to be decrypted according to the user actions:

For point number 3, I think to:

- use an index mechanism to quickly find the data to decrypt.
- use a C/C++ function to do the decryption on Android, using a Java/JNI bridge

Any other suggestions or methods from other experimented Android and iPhone/iPad developers ?

Comment: If your user must not be able to read your files, don't put the files on _their_ device. What you want is DRM and we're all aware of how much trouble even the gurus have with implementing such a thing.

Comment: The data **MUST** be on the device! This app will be used in environments where networks (WiFi, 3G...) are not available

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there's no way to store data on an external medium like an SD card on the iPhone.

This being said, what you like to achieve is impossible. If some encrypted data is meant to be decrypted on the device (even if only partially), this means the app needs to store the decryption key. This in itself is insecure, even with code obfuscation it is still technically possible for a motivated attacker to retrieve that key by reverse engineering your app.

So, if that data *must* not be made freely available through a malicious attack, don't store it in the device.

And even if you don't store it locally but instead transmit the decrypted data through a secure channel as needed - there's attacks for that, too.

It all boils down to this: There's always a vulnerability that may be exploited. You can try making it as hard for an attacker as possible to break in, but you must always keep in mind that it might be possible after all.

Comment: I know that a motivated user can always crack the data. But what are the best technics to slow down this hacker? 
What's code obfuscation ? Adding some code that do actually nothing in order to send the hacker in a wrong way?

Comment: Things like that, yes. For example you might store parts of the decryption key in several locations of different types, add some salt to each location and then extract the parts at runtime and recombine them. Ideally, the code to recombine the key is divided into several parts as well.